# Can Use Case be broken down into multiple diagrams?

Tags: uml, use-case, flowchart

I am fairly new to UML especially use case. My question is should we divide use case to represent the flow of our systems?

For example, ***Party Management System*** has features like **Party control**, **Mission Control** and **Participant Control**. One participant can join many parties and parties can have many participants.

Users after login can choose **All parties** they currently enroll  through **Show Party** button. Parties can be created by users and thus they will become **Host** so that they can invite **Participants** to join and give them **Missions**.
Selecting one party will direct user to **Party Name** page. From there, **Host** can *Invite* Participants via **Participant Control** tab, change their role into **Host** or **Participant** handle **Mission** to them in **Mission Control** tab contained in a specific **Party**.
**Host** can change party type to *Open/Invite Only* in **Party Control** tab or change name and date.
Only host can modify **Party Details** and assign **Mission**, participants can view missions that are assigned to them but cannot modify anything. All the tabs are placed at a Left Side Menu Bar.

We have 2 primary actors, **Host** and **Participants**. So my question begins here:

***1***. Should I divide use case to 4 use cases: **All Parties** (which will have **Show Party** process), **Party Control**, **Mission Controls**, **Participant Controls** just like the basic flow of the system (After login, users are in dashboard. From Dashboard, Choose **Show Party**—> **Party Control**, **Mission Control**, **Participant Control**)?

***2.*** With each Use Case diagrams, I will add a Flow Chart to further illustrate how users interact with system, if just one Use Case diagram is need in this case, should I break down those features into many Flow Charts?

Thank you for reading my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No! What you are talking of is functional decomposition and that is not part of use case (diagrams). A use case "just" shows the added value it gives to an actor of the system under consideration.

When it comes to implementation details or "user stories" you can either use a Cockburn-like textual description or choose activity diagrams. It's also possible to have a mix if you have complex scenarios. However, there shouldn't be an overlap since then you have the question: which one tells the truth. Edits over time will likely diverge and leave some mess behind.

As always I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases!

P.S. Basically [@Christophe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe) and my answer are similar or at least they do not contradict. I'm just stressing a bit more that functional decomposition is a no-go on use case level.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use-cases **can be broken down into several distinct diagrams** that each show a part of the larger model.

But no, **not a breakdown by flow**: Use-cases are not for modeling flows. Use cases should correspond to user goals and should not to show how these goals shall be achieved:

- for user interface details (e.g. the button, which leads to a feature, then the next...) you may use [wireframes](https://balsamiq.com/learn/articles/?gclid=CjwKCAjwj6SEBhAOEiwAvFRuKE5AdxHhm6aS8FMjt0XfZliIltBwbmD469Tt_u_zLYtktSR7TnkiaRoC3PcQAvD_BwE#/wireframing)
- for a more global design of user experience, you may consider [story boards](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/storyboards-visualize-ideas/) or [user journey maps](https://stephaniewalter.design/blog/an-introduction-to-user-journey-map-pdf-templates/).
- for a detailed flow of control or objects, you may consider activity diagrams instead of flow charts. In fact an activity diagram can specify a behaviors that allows to achieve a complex use case. However, withstand the temptation of “visual programming”.

But the use-case itself should be independent of how it is implemented and leave freedom for user-centric UI design. What can this system do for its users is the main question the diagram should answer.

Comment: Actually I'd say _it must be independent_ not just _should_ since if not so it's the start of functional decomposition. And that would be just wrong.

Comment: @qwerty_so I agree, but I’m still looking for a wording claiming more strongly the UC independence, while at the same time not completely preventing extension and inclusion which express some kind of dependency.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Hmm. I know what your issue is. I can only talk for myself that I'm rather strict in many aspects (which of course gives me contradicting statements/replies). Just see my answer ;-)

Comment: UC can of course be broken down but only in a very limited way. If you are doing such a break down you are already starting functional decomposition. Include/extend are in fact bad concepts since they are used the wrong way so often.

Comment: @qwerty_so what I meant to say is that not all use cases have to be shown in a single diagram. The model is more than a single UC diagram. For a large system you can very well have UC diagrams organized by topics. It’s not necessarily functional decomposition.

Comment: Oh, I did not see your edit. I think that's now a perfect statement. Nonetheless, I think that the OP is actually targeting functional decomposition which is why I started my answer with "no" ;-)